# Ansible ad-hoc command works but same doesn't work in ansible playbook

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

I'm able to run the raw module using Ansible ad-hoc commands however, when run the playbook with same commands it fails with error:

```
invalid output was: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible-tmp-1418879078.47-138258829915016/setup", line 187, in <module>
    import locale
ImportError: No module named locale
```

Any idea what I might be missing or how should I write the playbook to reflect the same as I'm doing in ad-hoc command.

My ad-hoc command is:

```
sudo ansible locale1 -i data --private-key=server.pem -vvvv -u ubuntu -m script -a multivr.sh
```

Where **miltivr.sh** is a small script in bash that removes the **multiverse.list**.
locale1 is a tag in my inventory file to tell ansible which hosts I need to run this command on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: would this be better on serverfault.com?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use [apt_repository](http://docs.ansible.com/apt_repository_module.html) module to manage your repos, instead of a shell script.

```
# Remove specified repository from sources list.
apt_repository: repo='deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse'
                state=absent
```

Comment: RAW module I'm using because python installation on my hosts is corrupted so apt_repository module doesn't work either. So the steps I'm following: 1. Remove multiverse using commands through RAW module 2. Update the apt repository 3. Install python. The output when I run the apt_repository module as you suggested: "invalid output was: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible-tmp-1419137916.08-106638061550345/setup", line 187, in <module>
    import locale
ImportError: No module named locale" Any other suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Then please update your question to indicate that you have a broken Python. And you still have not shown your playbook like I requested in the original comment.